# Can you texture an object with a camera's render every frame? (animation in an animation)

Tags: animation, texturing, camera, blend-files, packed-data

[image: desired result]

So what I want to do is animate a texture on an object using a camera's view of other objects in the same .blend file (possibly in another Scene.) As the animated objects under the texture camera move, the rendered texture is applied to a main object that is rendered on a main camera for the main animation.

In other words, as the objects under one camera move, the rendering of their movement is applied as a texture to another object while THAT object is rendered as part of a bigger animation.

Anybody have any ideas on how to pull this off? I can try to elaborate more if needed.

Comment: This could possibly create a paradoxical situation of infinite recursion. I don't think this is possible in Blender as far as I know. At least not the exact same frame, maybe with a one frame delay(?)